# How to properly use Grails Command Objects

Tags: grails

I've been struggling for a while reading and trying to understand command objects, but I've yet to understand how to use them in my particular scenario.

**Here's what I have:**

```
class Beneficary {
  String name
  //more attributes

  static hasMany = [dependents = Dependent]
}

class Dependent { 
  DegreeKinship degreeKinship //enum
  //several atrributes

  static belongsTo = [beneficiary: Beneficiary]
}
```

I've read in several articles, including SO answers, that one should be using Command Objects for this if one wishes  but I'm failing to understand just how.

I've wrote this:

```
class DependentCommand {
  List<Dependent> dependents = ListUtils.lazyList([], {new Dependent()} as Factory)
}
```

but I'm not sure how to use it in my `Beneficiary` class.

Also, I wish to have it all under a single view (`beneficiary/create`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should use them in the Beneficary class, use them in BeneficaryController.

Command objects give you a standardized way of encapsulating, converting and validating request parameters. As such the main use for them is in a controller, not a domain class which can already do most of a command object's functions natively.

You could rewrite your command like this if you wanted to accept a request containing parameters along the lines of `dependents=1&dependents=2`:

```
class DependentCommand {
    List<Dependent> dependents
}
```

Comment: This answer makes less sense to me than the question.  What are you expecting `source['dependents']` to evaluate to here and why would you want to write your own code there to load the instances instead of letting the framework do that for you (which it can do)?

Comment: Thank you, I remember not being able to make it work, hence the code which was copy&pasted (badly apparently) from a project of mine. I tested again and it works like a charm now. Reply edited.